# Windows Terminal clickable urls?

Tags: windows, terminal, hyperlink, clickable

Can you `ctrl+click` a URL in Windows Terminal to open the link in the default browser? I can't find the option anywhere; is there some package I need to install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current public stable release, you can't. You need to manually select, copy, and paste the URL from the terminal window to your browser. As listed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/terminal-v2-roadmap.md), that feature is listed in the roadmap to version 2.0.

Comment: Time for WT to add plugin support.

Comment: What about now 2022?

Comment: @MrEduar Yes, now it is available. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to use the feature before Windows Terminal `2.0` is released, it's available in the `1.4` release of Windows Terminal Preview. See the [release document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-4-release/).

---

**Update**: this is now available as of in [`Windows Terminal v1.5.10271.0`](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.5.10271.0) - it is referred to as "Support for automatic detection of URLs".